# Dropdown flips up on resizing the browser(IE only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I created a drop down as

```
<body>
    <div style="height:200px"></div>
    <form id="myForm">
    <select style="margin-left:200px">
        <option value="">Select a vehicle</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
```

which appears in Internet explorer as normal. That is on click, the dropdown flips down. But if we resize the browser window and click the dropdown, it flips up with the list starting from the top. Is there any css solution for making the dropdown always flips down. Or can we make it using javascript or jquery? And this problem is only with the Internet Explorer.

Comment: no, the browsers picks out where to open it, according to what side (top/bottom) has more/enough room.

Comment: This is not a bug. All browsers determine how best to position the dropdown.

Comment: Changing the default behavior would be annoying, if anything. I really see no reason why this should be possible. Maybe you are trying to solve an XY problem?